# @media rule - force new line in NavBar and display previously right aligned links in this line but center aligned

Tags: css, html, media

I have a `NavBar` with my name left aligned(green background color), and then links to other pages which are right aligned(no background color). When re-sizing to less than `640px` I need to move the right aligned links to a new line, and center all `NavBar` content. I cannot get the links to move to a second line.

HTML:

```css
/* menu bar */
header{
 background-color: #ffffff;
 height: 60px;
 margin: 0;
 padding:0;
  }

ul{
 list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display:block;

  }
/* align right */
li{
  float:right;
  }
/*link formatting*/
li a{
  display:block;
  padding: 8px;
  color:black;
  text-align: center;
  padding:10px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: bold;
  }
/* name with background color*/
li:last-child{
  font-size: 34px; 
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position:absolute;
  float:left;
  }


@media screen and (max-width: 640px) {
 
li:last-child{
  font-size: 34px; 
  background-color: #4aaaa5;
  position:absolute;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0px;
  }

}
```

```html
<ul>
   
 <li><a id="bottomlinks"href="index.html">About</a></li>

 <li><a id="bottomlinks"href="portfolio.html">Portfolio</a></li>

 <li><a id="bottomlinks"href="contact.html">Contact</a></li>

 <li><a href="#"> Mark Ring</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Your Code Snippet doesn't reflect what you've described in your post. I'm not seeing anything being left or right aligned.

Comment: If you run the snippet you will see "Mark Ring" centered with a background of green. The rest of the UL list disappears, I need it to appear under the name, with a background of white.

Comment: You'll be more likely to get help if you clean up your snippet to contain only the code that causes you problems and nothing else. In your @media block you have a lot of rules for elements that are not even in your html...

Comment: Removed as much as I could, you will see at the end of the CSS I formatted the name with the @media, but I am not sure how to approach the remaining list items. Sorry for the confusion first time posting a question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a basic demo of what it looks like you're attempting to achieve. As you can see I've simplified the HTML and CSS a bit.

Hope it helps!

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
ul,
li {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
}
header {
  text-align: center;
  overflow: hidden; /* clearfix */
}
.brand {
  display: block;
  background-color: #4AAAA5;
  line-height: 60px;
}

@media ( min-width: 640px ) {
  header {
    text-align: left;
    height: 60px;
  }
  .nav {
    float: right;
  }
  .nav li {
    float: left;
    line-height: 60px;
  }
  .brand {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a class="brand" href="#">Brand</a>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    <li><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

In your code you were absolute positioning the brand element on top of the other links (couldn't see them) and didn't undo the float (which kept them from stacking vertically).

Comment: Thank you for the response, this displayed a list of vertical centered links all with the background color green. I was trying to get the Brand 100% width Background Green, next line remaining items horizontally aligned no background color.

Comment: Not sure how much green you were looking to have when everything is on one line but is now limited to the `.brand` element when minimized.